# Terragrunt dependency list output as inputs

Tags: terragrunt

I have two entrypoints: s3 and do_something.
s3 is a dependency for do_something and has the following code:

terragrunt.hcl

```
aws_regions = [ "us-east-1", "eu-east-1" ]
inputs = {
  build_bucket = {
    "${local.aws_regions[0]}" = {
      name = "somename-${local.aws_regions[0]}"
    }
    "${local.aws_regions[1]}" = {
      name = "somename-${local.aws_regions[1]}"
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "build_bucket" {
  for_each = var.build_bucket
  bucket = each.value["name"]
  acl    = "private"
}
output "build_bucket" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.build_bucket[*]
}
```

--terragrunt-debug is looking like:

```
  "build_bucket": [
    [
      {
        "eu-east-1": {
          "acceleration_status": "",
          "acl": "private",
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::somename-eu-east-1",
          "bucket": "somename-eu-east-1",
        },
        "us-east-1": {
          "acceleration_status": "",
          "acl": "private",
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::somename-us-east-1",
          "bucket": "somename-us-east-1",
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
```

In do_something folder I have the terragrunt.hcl:

```
dependency "s3" {
  config_path = "../s3"
}
inputs = {
  build_bucket = [dependency.s3-build.outputs.build_bucket]
}
```

vars.tf

```
variable "build_bucket" {
  description = "S3 buckets"
  type = list
}
```

How can I get each element of build_bucket?

This didn't worked:

```
var.build_bucket[0].[data.aws_region.current.name].bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested lists...
Variable set to any instead of string.

```
variable "build_bucket_arn" {
  description = "S3 bucket ARN for the builds"
  type = any
```

Calling the raw nested lists:

```
var.build_bucket[0][0][data.aws_region.current.name].bucket
```